# Is there any way to remove remove additional header in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

so, is there any extension or setting, which can convert headers like this:

[image: Gnome standard header]

to headers like this:

[image: Prefered header]

Im using ubuntu 21.10

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question properly. Which OS are you running? Which version? This is needed at a minimum to offer an answer 

Comment: Ask VSCode developers to realize top bar as it done in Chromium / Google Chrome. Or maybe find a plugin for VSCode.

Comment: there is also same thing for another apps. Like intellij IDE and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please check out [**Unite Gnome Extension**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/).

> Unite is a GNOME Shell extension which makes a few layout tweaks to the top panel and removes window decorations to make it look like Ubuntu Unity Shell.

Comment: thanks! thats exactly what i need